# Moment of inertia

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to find moment of inertia of thin circular loop of radius $R$ and mass $m.$

The moment of inertia of the ring is in relation to the $x$ and $z$ axes (mass is distributed in the $xy$ plane, and the axis of rotation is the $z$ axis, for one calculation, and the $x$ axis for the other.)

$m = 2\pi R\lambda$

$C=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=R^2, z=0\}$

$$I_z=\lambda \oint_C(x^2+y^2)\,ds\;  \text{and}\; I_x=\lambda\oint_C(y^2+z^2)\,ds$$

$\lambda$ is a constant.

Already done:
$$I_x=\int_{0}^{2\pi}y^2\cdot \lambda r\, d\theta  ,\  I_y=\int_{0}^{2\pi}x^2\cdot \lambda r \,d\theta
\; \text{and}\;  I_z=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\big(x^2+y^2\big)\cdot \lambda r \,d\theta=I_x+I_y,$$

where $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ and $\lambda$ is the linear density.

How I take it from there?

Comment: About which axis are you rotating the loop?

Comment: Rotating axis are z and x axis

Comment: That answer makes no sense. Whenever you calculate a moment of inertia, the result is dependent on the distribution of mass about ***the*** axis of rotation. There can only be one axis of rotation for a given moment of inertia calculation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#/media/File:Moment_of_inertia_hoop.svg

Comment: That is the case what I am dealing with

Comment: So, do you need to calculate two separate moments of inertia, one about the $x$ axis and one about the $z$ axis?

Comment: Yes one about x-axis which is 1/2*m*r^2 and one for z-axis which is m*r^2.

Answer (score 1):

Without doing the integration, notice first that $I_x+I_y=I_z$.  Also, $I_x=I_y$ due to symmetry, so $I_x=I_y=\frac{1}{2}I_z$.  But for $I_z$, every part of the ring is at the same distance $R$ from the axis of rotation, so $I_z=mR^2$.  This gives $I_x=I_y=\frac12mR^2$.

Answer (score 0):

So everything looks good so far:
\begin{align*}
I_x&=\lambda\int_{0}^{2\pi}y^2r\, d\theta\\
&=\lambda\int_{0}^{2\pi}r^2\sin^2(\theta)\,r\, d\theta\\
&=\lambda r^3\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2(\theta)\, d\theta\\
&=\frac{m}{2\pi r}\,r^3\,\pi\\
&=\frac{mr^2}{2},
\end{align*}
as required. You can substitute in similarly for the $I_z$ integral and you should get the right result.